# Vertical slick carousel arrows

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I am trying to make a vertical slick carousel but I have no idea how to make the arrows vertical as well

```
$('.offer-page-carousel').slick({
    arrows: true,
    vertical: true,
    prevArrow: false,
    verticalSwiping: true,
});
```

I only want nextArrow to be displayed. Currently the arrow is on the right of the carousel (as default). I want it to be at the bottom of the carousel. Any way I can achieve this with CSS?

Comment: have you tried like this https://jsfiddle.net/devpull/q827wb0a/

Comment: @UdhayTitus The carousel is already scrolling vertically... it's just the arrows

Comment: `prevArrow` is a `string (html|jQuery selector)` not a bool type

Comment: @Jason do you have any fiddle..???

Answer (score 1):

This will position the default slick navigation vertically. You'll need to play with the sizes if your buttons are larger:

```css
.slick-slider {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(90deg);
}
.slick-next {
  top: unset;
  bottom: -30px;
}
.slick-prev {
  top: -30px;
}
```

Working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/ftadv6g1/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrows: false`. For example, this is how I wrote my JavaScript code to get rid of those left and right arrows that Slick carousel provides by default:

```
$('#slickcarousel').slick({
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000
});
```

Then you can build your own arrows and style them with CSS. This is how I specified the arrows in my JavaScript code:

```
$('.left').click(function(){
    $('#slickcarousel').slick('slickPrev');
});
$('.right').click(function(){
    $('#slickcarousel').slick('slickNext');
});
```

The CSS code:

```
#testimonials .left{cursor:pointer;margin:9px 0 16px 16px}
#testimonials .right{cursor:pointer;margin:9px 16px 24px 0;float:right}
```

The HTML for the buttons:

```
<img class="left" src="/img/arrowleft.png" width="32" height="31" alt="Arrow left button">
<img class="right" src="/img/arrowright.png" width="32" height="31" alt="Arrow right button">
```

The result:

[image]